# Images disappear when minimize windows into a JavaFX app

Tags: java, swing, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

I'm fixing a JavaFX application on JDK 8. The app shows multiple images using something like "jLabel.setIcon(new Image(...))". I know their is a component to show images in JavaFX but it is not the issue (because I'm not allowed to modify neither that part from the source nor the FXML files).

My problem is when minimize or change the window ((using ALT+TAB)) and wait some time (even up 1 hour approx) to come back to the window, this doesn't show the images anymore. However, if I move the window, the images come back.

In an attempt to fix the problem (independently of use the minimize button or ALT+TAB), I added in the final of the init() method this piece of code:

```
public void init() {
    ...
    stage.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldvalue, newvalue) -> {
        if (newvalue) repaintImages();
    });
}

private void repaintImages() {
    Object obj = new Object();

    synchronized (obj) {
        jLabel.repaint();
        jLabel.revalidate();

        obj.notify();
    }

    try {
        obj.wait();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

The code before runs repaintImages() after the windows is focused. I used synchronized with the idea to be ensured the code is executed in thread-safe (independently of lag), Anyway that doesn't fix the problem (images are missing yet). After that, I change this the code to use runLater():

```
public void init() {
    ...
    stage.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldvalue, newvalue) -> {
        if (newvalue) Platform.runLater(()->{repaintImages();});
    });
}

private void repaintImages() {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        jLabel.repaint();
        jLabel.revalidate();
    });                         
}
```

And it doesn't work either. Please, any suggestion is welcome.

I know, I wrote a long question, but maybe a suggestion could be to move the window when it is focused. In that case, please give the correct way to do this because I tried and not worked too (using synchronized and runLater()). This is the piece of code I used to move the window (placing this into a synchronized block or in the lambda function in runLater()):

```
Translate elements = null;

if (positive_flag) {
    elements = new Translate(1, 0, 0);
    positive_flag = false;
} else {
    elements = new Translate(-1, 0, 0);
    positive_flag = true;
}

anchorPane.getTransforms().addAll(elements);
```

Finally, consider that to prove if any solution works, I need to wait even up 1h.

Comment: You might have hit a bug - hard to tell, without a runnable example ;) Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly.

Comment: hmm ... are you mixing swing and fx?

Comment: Yes @kleopatra. That's not my source code, for that reason I'm not allowed to modify the way they renderized the window elements. They added a _swing-JLabel_ to _swing-JPanel_ and put it into a _JavaFX-SwingNode_ element (using `createAndSetSwingContentPage(...)`) and finally they put this into a _JavaFX-Pane_. The way to change the image is `JLabel.SetIcon(new ImageIcon(new Image(...)))`.

Comment: okay then back to my first comment :) Without providing a mcve you most probably wont get much help ...